# SQL Show records that meet a provided criteria

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity

I have the following table

```
CamId   RegNumber   DateSeen
5        G1234B     18/02/2014 11:54
3        G1234B     18/02/2014 11:51
5        G11854     18/02/2014 11:50
3        G11854     18/02/2014 11:49
3        G24581     18/02/2014 11:48
5        G24581     18/02/2014 11:47
```

I would like to retrieve all records with CamId 3 that do not have a later entry in CamId 5 based on the dateseen entry on CamId 3 for that particular reg number.

From the sampe data table above the system should return just one number plate G24581 as it has no later entries in CamId 5.

Comment: are you wanting this as SQL or EF query?

Answer (score 0):

One method you can employ is to join onto the table twice so that in one table you have the values where CamID is 3 and the other is 5.  Then you would want to get all records from the first table that do no have a record in the second table.

```
Select A.* from Table A
LEFT JOIN ( Select * from Table ) B on A.RegNumber = B.RegNumber AND A.CamID = 3 and B.CamID = 5 AND A.DateSeen <= B.DateSeen
WHERE B.CamID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query = from r1 in db.Regs
            where r1.CamId == 3 &&
            !db.Regs.Any(r2 => r2.CamId==5 && r2.DateSeen>r1.DateSeen && r2.RegNumber==r1.RegNumber)
            select r1;
```